# Python web-framework+db with the widest scalability?

Tags: python, database, api, scalability, web-frameworks

I am building a project requiring high performance and scalability, entailing:

- [Role-based authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) with [API-key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface_key) licensing to access data of specific users
- [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) exposed with [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) ([XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML), [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)), [XMLRPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLRPC), [JSONRPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONRPC) and [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP)
- "Easily" configurable [getters and setters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) to create APIs accessing the same data but with input/output in different [schemas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema)

A conservative estimate of the number of tables—often whose queries require joins—is: 20.

Which database type—e.g.: [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) or [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_management_system)—[key-value data store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_data_store) or [object-relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_database)—e.g.: [Redis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis) or [PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL)—and [web-framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework)—e.g. [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29), [Web2Py](http://www.web2py.com/) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)—would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web frameworks you mention they all scale the same and with 20 tables they probably have similar performance. The bottle neck will always be the database. You mention joins. That means you need a relational database. I would not over-engineer it. Make it work. Polish it. Than make it scale but adding extensive caching.

Answer (score 5):

The bullet point description you have provided would adequately describe just about any data-backed web site on the planet with an API. You haven't provided anywhere near enough detail to provide meaningful recommendations.

Each of the technologies you have mentioned have strengths and weaknesses. However, those strengths and weaknesses are only relevant in the context of a specific problem.

The choice of RDBMS over NoSQL solution depends on the type of data you're intending to store, and the relationship between those data. It depends on the read/write patterns that you're expecting to see. It depends on the volume of data you're expecting to be storing and retrieving. It depends on the specific set of features you need your data store to have.

The choice of web framework depends on the complexity of what you're building, and the resources the community around those tools can provide to support you building your site. That means the community of libraries, and the community of developers who you can call on to support your development.

In short, there is no silver bullet. Work out your requirements, and pick the tool or tools that suit those requirements. The answer won't always be the same.